# How to pass a command line argument using WScript.Shell in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, background

I am trying to run a php script in the background, which is called from another php file:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("php -f admin_mailer/ideamailer.class.php arg1 arg2 arg3", 0, false);
```

The file runs...my problem is that the arguments are not passed. I have print_r($argv) in the executed file which just displays a '1'. What is the correct way to pass arguments? I am on a windows server.

Comment: Is there are any precautions for that statement to work: `new COM("WScript.Shell");` ? Because it isn't working for me ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can run the commands with parameters exactly this way, try to escape the parameters to the function [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)

Comment: Ah thanks that worked. I had spaces in the argument string which was messing it up. Also I discovered the print_r($argv) wasnt working as I expected, and had to directly refer to the $var i.e. $argv[1].